What will be to location of a minor body after a collision
Consider two celestial bodies that are orbiting each other in a circular orbit, we denote it as $M$ and $m$, respectively.
A third body comes in and impact the the smaller body, this results a change in $m$'s orbit, turning it into an ellipse. My question is right after the collision, will $m$ be in the perihelion of the ellipse or the aphelion of the ellipse?
My thoughts:
I expect it will be in the aphelion of the ellipse, since after collision, the velocity of $m$ will decrease, thus "falling" to $M$, after it come close to $M$, it will gain velocity (conservation of angular momentum) and come back again, but conservation of angular momentum gives that the maximum distance that $m$ can reach will not exceed the original circular orbit's radius, so right after the collision, $m$ will be in the aphelion of the ellipse.
I also asked chatgpt about this, it says that $m$ will be in the perihelion of the elliptical orbit. Which makes me super confused now.
Any help is appreciated!


the velocity of $m$ will decrease

Not necessarily. The answer to this depends entirely on how $m$ is struck. Given the current velocities of $m$ and the impactor, solve for the new velocity. If the impactor fuses with $m$, you have a perfectly inelastic collision, so use conversation of momentum to find the new velocity of $m+I$.
Now you know the new velocity, $\mathbf{v}$, and the radial vector to $M$, $\mathbf{r}$. You can follow the steps on the Wiki page for Elliptic orbit under Equation of Motion. You first find the semimajor axis by
$$a = \frac{GM r}{2GM - rv^2}$$
Then calculate the eccentricity vector
$$\mathbf{e}= \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} - \frac{\mathbf{v}\times (\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v})}{GM} $$
Finally, since we have an elliptic orbit, body $M$ is at one of the foci, the origin of this coordinate system. The empty focus is at
$$\mathbf{F}_2 = -2a\mathbf{e}$$
Now you can draw out the whole ellipse and see where in the path your orbiting body is. I think if $m$ is struck at some angle not along its current orbit, it will be at neither periapsis or apoapsis in the new orbit, but I haven't worked out an example to see.
